# Can I check if a pin code is made out of numbers using ASCII?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if a pin code is made out of numbers only.

It is a challenge from codewars. Most of them use jQuery to solve this, but I'm not familiar with it, and I thought it would work with ASCII.

```
function validatePIN(pin) {
  for (var i = 0; i < pin.length; i++) {
    if ((pin.length === 4 || pin.length === 6) && (pin.charCodeAt(i) >= 48 && pin.charCodeAt(i) < 58)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

When I test with "1q23", for example, the return is true. But if I test with "q123", the result is false. I'm a beginner, so go easy :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to learn how to debug JavaScript and look at your usage of the for loop in combination with return.

Answer (score 0):

You're just checking the first value. Put your `return true` after your `for` loop. Basically you want to exit the loop and return `false` if you find a non-number. Otherwise if you get through the loop without finding a number, you return `true`.

Comment: I know i shounld't say just 'thanks', but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You're returning value from for loop on first iteration itself, so on first iteration if your `if` condition evaluates true you're returning true, if not you're returning false,

Whereas what you should actually do is first check inside loop if any of condition fails return false, it not then at the end of function return true or false based on length of PIN

```js
function validatePIN(pin) {
  for (var i = 0; i < pin.length; i++) {
    if ((pin.charCodeAt(i) < 48 || pin.charCodeAt(i) > 58)) {
      return false;
    } 
  }
  return (pin.length === 4 || pin.length === 6) ? true : false
}


console.log(validatePIN('1q23'))
```

Alternate way to check

```js
const validatePIN = (val) => (val.length === 4 || val.length === 6) && !isNaN(val)

console.log(validatePIN('1q23'))
console.log(validatePIN('1234'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check only for `false` condition, that means return False if any of its characters is not a digit. Also I did a modification of your code that is the length condition, it can be the parent scope of `for` loop which might reduce extra checking.

```js
function validatePIN(pin) {
    if (pin.length === 4 || pin.length === 6) {
        for (var i = 0; i < pin.length; i++) {
            if (pin.charCodeAt(i) < 48 || pin.charCodeAt(i) > 58) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    return  false;
}

console.log(validatePIN('1q23'));
console.log(validatePIN('q23'));
```